# selecting combobox item using ui automation

Tags: c#, wpf

how do I select **ComboBox's SelectedIndex = -1?**

I wrote a code to automate testing:

```
AutomationElement aeBuildMachine = null;
int count = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nLooking for Build Machine Combo Box");
    aeBuildMachine = aeTabitemmain.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "ListBoxItem"));
    if (aeBuildMachine == null)
          throw new Exception("No Build Machine Combo Box");
    else
          Console.WriteLine("Found Build Machine Combo Box");
    ++count;
 }
while (aeBuildMachine == null && count < 50);

Console.WriteLine("Selecting Build machine from combobox...");
SelectionItemPattern spBuildmachine = (SelectionItemPattern)aeBuildMachine.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
```

How do I use this `SelectionItemPattern`?

Answer (score 27):

This is about **100 times more complicated** than it needs to be, but I finally got it working.  The big issue with the WPF ComboBox is that as far as Automation goes, it doesn't appear to have any ListItems **until the ComboBox has been expanded**.

The following code uses the ExpandCollapse pattern to momentarily drop down the list and then collapse it, then it can use FindFirst on the ComboBox to get the ListItem to be selected, and then use the SelectionItem pattern to select it.

In the case of the original question, a selection of -1 means no items selected.  There is no method for this, but you could simply use FindAll to get a collection of ListItems, get the SelectionItem pattern for each one in turn and call its RemoveFromSelection method.

```
    public static void SetSelectedComboBoxItem(AutomationElement comboBox, string item)
    {
        AutomationPattern automationPatternFromElement = GetSpecifiedPattern(comboBox, "ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern");

        ExpandCollapsePattern expandCollapsePattern = comboBox.GetCurrentPattern(automationPatternFromElement) as ExpandCollapsePattern;

        expandCollapsePattern.Expand();
        expandCollapsePattern.Collapse();

        AutomationElement listItem = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, item));

        automationPatternFromElement = GetSpecifiedPattern(listItem, "SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern");

        SelectionItemPattern selectionItemPattern = listItem.GetCurrentPattern(automationPatternFromElement) as SelectionItemPattern;

        selectionItemPattern.Select();
    }

    private static AutomationPattern GetSpecifiedPattern(AutomationElement element, string patternName)
    {
        AutomationPattern[] supportedPattern = element.GetSupportedPatterns();

        foreach (AutomationPattern pattern in supportedPattern)
        {
            if (pattern.ProgrammaticName == patternName)
                return pattern;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would share this as a simple way to select any item from a ComboBox or other item container:

```
protected AutomationElement GetItem(AutomationElement element, string item)
    {
        AutomationElement elementList;
        CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest();
        cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
        cacheRequest.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children;

        elementList = element.GetUpdatedCache(cacheRequest);

        foreach (AutomationElement child in elementList.CachedChildren)
            if (child.Cached.Name == item)
                return child;

        return null;
    }
```

element is the ComboBox or item container, item is the string name or literal value of the item in the container.  Once you have the item you can do the following to select it:

```
protected void Select(AutomationElement element)
    {
        SelectionItemPattern select = (SelectionItemPattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
        select.Select();
    }
```

Hope this helps others.  I derived this pattern from the MSDN documentation on Automation, found here:

[MSDN - Automation and Cached Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.cachedchildren.aspx)

Comment: Not sure why, but for my project, select.Select() will throw an exception if select is the currently selected element. - Win32 target if that makes a difference

Comment: Using Cached request you made it complex.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method to select item from comboxbox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="comboBox">Combobox Element</param>
    /// <param name="item">Item to select</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SelectComboboxItem(this AutomationElement comboBox, string item)
    {
        if (comboBox == null) return false;
        // Get the list box within the combobox
        AutomationElement listBox = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List));
        if (listBox == null) return false;
        // Search for item within the listbox
        AutomationElement listItem = listBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, item));
        if (listItem == null) return false;
        // Check if listbox item has SelectionItemPattern
        object objPattern;
        if (true == listItem.TryGetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern, out objPattern))
        {
            SelectionItemPattern selectionItemPattern = objPattern as SelectionItemPattern;
            selectionItemPattern.Select(); // Invoke Selection
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Usage

```
        AutomationElement paymentCombobox = element.FindFirst(
            TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "cbPayment")
        );
        paymentCombobox.SelectComboboxItem("Cash");
```

resource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you leave some comments in the code to describe what your code does?

Comment: `SelectComboboxItem` Extension method must inside static class to make it work

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern_members(v=VS.85).aspx

That is the answer to your question as I understood it.

But.. is it really your question?

Anyhow, you can add or remove SelectableItems from a selection which - I suppose - belong to its parent, same goes for some other things like checking whether they are selected.

Comment: Or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.selectionitempattern_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx if you prefer the English MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the easiest way for a simple generic ComobBox value setter this one is fine provided the list items in the ComboBox doesn't have duplicates.

```
private void SetCombobValueByUIA( AutomationElement ctrl, string newValue )
{ 
    ExpandCollapsePattern exPat = ctrl.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern) 
                                                              as ExpandCollapsePattern;

    if( exPat== null )
    {
        throw new ApplicationException( "Bad Control type..." );
    }

    exPat.Expand();

    AutomationElement itemToSelect = ctrl.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new
                          PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty,newValue));

    SelectionItemPattern sPat = itemToSelect.GetCurrentPattern(
                                              SelectionItemPattern.Pattern)  as SelectionItemPattern ; 
    sPat. Select();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a big change but only a few to notice,

1. Don't need to use collapse pattern, calling expand will do the trick for you.
2. Using `treescope.subtree` worked for me instead of children.

The code sample would be like this,

```
public static void SelectValueInComboBox(string comboBox, string value)
{
    var comboBoxElement = HelperMethods.FindElementFromAutomationID(comboBox);
    if (comboBoxElement == null)
        throw new Exception("Combo Box not found");

    ExpandCollapsePattern expandPattern = (ExpandCollapsePattern)comboBoxElement.GetCurrentPattern(ExpandCollapsePattern.Pattern);

    AutomationElement comboboxItem = comboBoxElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, value));

    SelectionItemPattern selectPattern = (SelectionItemPattern)comboboxItem.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
    selectPattern.Select();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer by gotmug required the CacheRequest to be activated. I implemented this as an extension method

```
 public static bool SelectDropDownItem(this AutomationElement comboBoxElement, string item)
        {
            bool itemFound = false;
            AutomationElement elementList;
            CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest();
            cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
            cacheRequest.TreeScope = TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children;

            using (cacheRequest.Activate())
            {
                // Load the list element and cache the specified properties for its descendants.
                Condition cond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List);
                elementList = comboBoxElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, cond);
            }

            //Loop thru and find the actual ListItem
            foreach (AutomationElement child in elementList.CachedChildren)
                if (child.Cached.Name == item)
                {
                    SelectionItemPattern select = (SelectionItemPattern)child.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern);
                    select.Select();
                    itemFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            return itemFound;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
  public static void SetComboBox(AutomationElement ComboxBox, string SelectedValue)
        {
            AutomationElement ListBox = ComboxBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "ListBox"));
            AutomationElement SelectedItem = ListBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, SelectedValue));
            ((SelectionItemPattern)SelectedItem.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern)).Select();
        }
```

Instruction on how to use:
1) Copy and Paste into Utility Class
2) Find your ComboBox AutomationElement
3) Utility.SetCombox(ComboxAutomationElement, "SelectedText")

To understand:

Tree structure of ComboBox as follow:

ComboBox->ListBox (children)->ListItems(children) [each combobox has a ListBox as a child, and the ListBox has all ListItems as children].

Each ListItem has SelectedItemPattern, invoke which you want to select.

I later found out that "Shaz " has better coding, and i vote him as the best code.

** Comment: To do UIAAutomation, you must map the AutomationElements of your application to a TreeView, which makes everything simple and understood.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in **`WindowsForms comboBox`**

**Usage**

```
comboBox.SetSelectedComboBoxItem("ValueYouWantToSelect");
```

**Add this `Class` to your project:**

```
public static class AutomationElementExtensions
    { 
        public static void InvokeControl(this AutomationElement element)
        {
            InvokePattern invokePattern = null;

            try
            {
                invokePattern =
                    element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)
                    as InvokePattern;
            }
            catch (ElementNotEnabledException)
            {
                // Object is not enabled
                return;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                // object doesn't support the InvokePattern control pattern
                return;
            }

            invokePattern.Invoke();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        } 


        public static void SetSelectedComboBoxItem(this AutomationElement comboBox, string item)
        {
            AutomationPattern automationPatternFromElement = GetSpecifiedPattern(comboBox, "ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern");

            ExpandCollapsePattern expandCollapsePattern = comboBox.GetCurrentPattern(automationPatternFromElement) as ExpandCollapsePattern;

            expandCollapsePattern.Expand();



            AutomationElement listItem = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, item));

            InvokeControl(listItem); 
        }

        private static AutomationPattern GetSpecifiedPattern(AutomationElement element, string patternName)
        {
            AutomationPattern[] supportedPattern = element.GetSupportedPatterns();

            foreach (AutomationPattern pattern in supportedPattern)
            {
                if (pattern.ProgrammaticName == patternName)
                    return pattern;
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```