# Select custom ComboBox item with UI Automation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, microsoft-ui-automation

How do I select an item in a custom ComboBox with Microsoft UI Automation? I have ComboBox that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rm8Function"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Functions}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Function, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource FunctionEnumConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I.e. I have overriden the ItemTemplate with a custom DataTemplate.

However, now I am not able to select the item using the answer on [selecting combobox item using ui automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814779/selecting-combobox-item-using-ui-automation):

```
public static void SelectComboBoxItem(this AutomationElement comboBox, string item)
{
    var expandCollapsePattern = comboBox.GetPattern<ExpandCollapsePattern>(ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern);
    expandCollapsePattern.Expand();
    expandCollapsePattern.Collapse();
    var listItem = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, item));
    var selectionItemPattern = listItem.GetPattern<SelectionItemPattern>(SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern);
    selectionItemPattern.Select();
}

public static T GetPattern<T>(this AutomationElement element, AutomationPattern pattern) where T: BasePattern
{
    try
    {
        return (T) element.GetCurrentPattern(pattern);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        element.PrintSupportedPatterns();
        throw;
    }
}
```

It throws an error telling me that `SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern` is an unsupported pattern. It's only `SynchronizedInputPatternIdentifiers.Pattern` that is supported by the element it's trying to select in the ComboBox.

How should I write my DataTemplate so that it becomes selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-defined my `ComboBox` in the following way:

```
<ComboBox AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Rm8Function"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Functions}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Function, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource FunctionEnumConverter}}"
                Text="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource FunctionEnumConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Giving the `TextBlock` the same `AutomationProperties.Name` value as its `Text` value.

I also updated my function that selects the ComboBox item to the following:

```
public static void SelectComboBoxItem(this AutomationElement comboBox, string item)
{
    var expandCollapsePattern = comboBox.GetPattern<ExpandCollapsePattern>(ExpandCollapsePatternIdentifiers.Pattern);
    expandCollapsePattern.Expand();
    expandCollapsePattern.Collapse();
    var listItem = comboBox.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, item));
    var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
    var parent = walker.GetParent(listItem);
    while (parent != comboBox)
    {
        listItem = parent;
        parent = walker.GetParent(listItem);
    }
    var selectionItemPattern = listItem.GetPattern<SelectionItemPattern>(SelectionItemPatternIdentifiers.Pattern);
    selectionItemPattern.Select();
}
```

Apparently, when using a `ComboBox` as-is without overriding the `ItemTemplate`, the function above finds its immediate child which is a `ListBoxItem`. It's the `ListBoxItem` that is selectable through the `SelectionItemPattern` pattern. But when overriding the `ItemTemplate`, the function instead finds the `TextBlock` that is a child to the `ListBoxItem`. Therefore, I had to modify my function in such a way that it traverses upwards until it finds the immediate child to the `ComboBox` and selects it.